# Best practice for spawning many time the same node in SpriteKit (swift)

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

In my game I spawn many enemies with random coordinates, but they share the same internal data.

Currently I have a function `SpawnEnemy()` who looks like this:

```
func spawnRedPawn(timer: NSTimer) {
    var redPawn = Ship(entityNamed: ESHIP_REDPAWN)
    let action = SKAction.moveToX(0, duration: timer.userInfo as! NSTimeInterval)
    let actionDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    redPawn.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width, y: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.size.height - redPawn.size.height))))
    redPawn.setupPhysicsBody(PC.enemy)
    redPawn.setupContactTestBitmask([PC.projectile, PC.player])
    redPawn.addEmitter("propulsionParticle", offset: CGPointMake(redPawn.size.width / 2 + 5, 0))
    redPawn.runAction(SKAction.sequence([action, actionDone]))
    self.addChild(redPawn)
}
```

*PS: the function format (called by NSTimer Selector()) will probably be changed*

I am new to SpriteKit but I feel that this setup process is quite resource intensive right?

My question is: is it possible/would it be better to run this fonction only once, and then only duplicate the created enemy?

Comment: Aside from performance question, note that NSTimer don't respect view's, scene's or node's paused state... So you should use SKAction for time related stuff.

Comment: I already use SKAction, the timer is used for creating a new enemy every X second (creating the node, setting the action, and running the action). Is it heresy?

Comment: @Mayers It could make a problem if you use NSTimer for that. Imagine that you spawn new enemy every five seconds, and eventually user pause the game...After some time, let's say a minute, because NSTimer don't respect the paused state of scene, you'll have a bunch of enemies on the screen. Which is not what you want...

Comment: Yhea i already experience this problem. I thought of making a class with function like `startTimer() pauseTimer() invalidateTimer()`.
Is that wrong? If so, do you have any insight of using Action as i use NSTimer?

Comment: That's another question, but I think everything is explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978854/3402095

Comment: Wow great forwarding. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some basics that you should know:

What you can do (especially if you are experiencing performance problems) is to:

- use texture atlases. This way you are reducing number of cpu draw calls required to render a sprites.
- cache different resources like emitters (or sounds). This way you are keep them in memory and you don't need to read them from disk.
  Search Apple's [Adventure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/BuildingtheWorld/BuildingtheWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH3-SW2) game to see how you can cache the resources. Basically, you preload everything before gameplay using the completion handler.

One way you could go is to pre-create a bunch of nodes and use them until game is finished. This way you won't re-create the SKSpriteNodes many times (which sometimes can cause noticeable lag). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29125538/3402095) you can read about that.

Important:

- Don't take simulator results into account, because those are not realistic. If you are interested in real information about performance you should test on device.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks for sharing these wise infos. I don't have performance issue, but I dont want to have to rethink my whole structure in few days when it will appear (if it appear, that's my question. What's your thoughts about that?)

Comment: @Mayerz It is always good idea to put everything "on paper" before actual apps implementation. Just be aware of premature optimization.

Comment: @Whirlwind - Agreed. I think every developer has had a problem with premature optimization at some point :)

Comment: Ok ok, i keep all these wises infos and keep developing, if i encounter problems I will turn back to this (excepted for the SKAction/NSTimer thing which I will replace immediately.) Thanks for all